# Securing endpoints in app engine using Android app

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

According to this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/add-authorization-backend) when you create the client ids for the endpoints you need a web client id, an android id and the audience parameter set equal to the web client id. Now since in the app you need to use something like that:

```
String aud = MY_WEB_ID;
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(context, aud);
```

I don't understand how the android id is managed because it seems it's never used. I created the android id and in the cloud console I set the package name for the app so the android id is bounded to my app, but it's actually never used, or at least is used in the endpoint but the client never use it. I hope someone can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The Android ID will be used to identify your app to the backend and not the user itself who will call the endpoint.

The Android ID is related to the certificate which will be used to sign your app. So you will have to create a second Android ID when you want to put your app into the Google Play Store because you will sign your app with the release certificate.

There will be not need to use the Android ID itself in your code.

Comment: I still don't understand how the android ID can identify the app since in the app I'm using the WEB id.